# Can’t retrieve any message to the Sentry page

Tags: c#, wpf, sentry

Goal:
Enable to track data whether it is error or not.

Problem:
I tried follow the instruction and when I execute the code, I still can’t get any error at sentry.io’s webpage.

What part am I missing?

Info:
*I’m newbie in Sentry
*I’m using the code from this picture

Thank you!

```
using Sentry;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

// https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/custom-exception-csharp

namespace SentryTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Student newStudent = null;

            try
            {
                newStudent = new Student();
                newStudent.StudentName = "James007";

                ValidateStudent(newStudent);
            }
            catch (InvalidStudentNameException ex)
            {

                using (SentrySdk.Init("https://472b09695026458c93638076efb9d666@o443014.ingest.sentry.io/5415884"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }


            }


        }

        private static void ValidateStudent(Student std)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]+$");

            if (!regex.IsMatch(std.StudentName))
                throw new InvalidStudentNameException(std.StudentName);

        }

    }


    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
    }


    [Serializable]
    class InvalidStudentNameException : Exception
    {
        public InvalidStudentNameException()
        {

        }

        public InvalidStudentNameException(string name)
            : base(String.Format("Invalid Student Name: {0}", name))
        {

        }

    }



}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The docs is trying to point out that all the application code has to be inside the `using` block. That is because before your app exits, the Sentry SDK wants have a chance to flush any queued events to Sentry's server.

Since WPF apps don't have a `Main` method, you can't really use the `using` approach, you'll need to hold a reference to the `IDisposable` returned from `SentrySdk.Init`.

You can call `SentrySdk.Init` in the constructor of the `App` class, and save the reference returned as a private field. Then when the app terminates, you call `Dispose` on it.

Something like:

```cs
private readonly IDisposable _sentry;

public App()
{
    // get your Sentry DSN here somehow, i.e.:
    var dsn = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SentryDsn"];
    _sentry = SentrySdk.Init(dsn);
}

protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnExit(e);
    // this makes sure Sentry sends out any queued events before the app exits
    _sentry.Dispose();
}
```

Now you can call `SentrySdk.CaptureException` or any other method of the Sentry SDK throughout your app.
The documentation on the [Sentry website has more information](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/guides/wpf/).

Comment: Thank you. A shame Sentry docs doesn't mention this.

Comment: There's a note ok n the doc about this. But the actual code snippet above could be added indeed